# WPF Integration From WinForm => Application.Current.Windows is wrong

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I run a WPF project from Winform Project with

```
    Dim frm2 As New EspBtpWpf.MainWindow("TableauBord", gEnv)
    Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(frm2)
    frm2.Show()
```

In my WPF project, i have a Main Windows (MainWindow) and an User Control (ucTableauBord).
My MainWindow Initialize the ucTableauBord into one of his Frame.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow(string pMode, SqiD23.Env pEnv=null)  {
            Classes.clsGlobal.EnsureApplicationResources(); // Lier le dictionnary aux ressources si on ne passe pas par le point d'entrée de l'application.
            ...
            LoadInterface(pMode);
        }

        public  MainWindow() :this("TableauBord") {
        }

        private void LoadInterface(string pMode) {
            if (pMode=="TableauBord") {
                navigateMain(new ucTableauBord());
            } else
                navigateMain(new ucBudgetDetaille());
        }

        /// <summary>Charge le userControl P dans le corps de la page principale.</summary>
        /// <param name="p">Instance du UserControl (new MyUserControl()).</param>
        public void navigateMain(UserControl p) {
            if ((frmMain.Content == null) || (frmMain.Content.ToString() != p.ToString()))
                frmMain.Content = p; // */
        }
}
```

And UserControl :

```
    public partial class ucTableauBord : ucTemplate {
        public ucTableauBord() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load();
        }

        private void Load() {
            ...
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>()) { // Retourne 0 car il ne voit que ucTableauBord lors du premier appel
                WinMain = (MainWindow)window;
            }
            if (WinMain != null) SetMsgMain("OK Load.");
        }
}
```

My problem is that i need to access to MainWindow since ucTableauBord.
But, on the first loading, the Application.Current.Windows dont contains the MainWindows, but a Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow element.
If i close the WPF Window (without close the WinForm project, and i load again the WPF project, the Application.Current.Windows contains the desired MainWindow.
And it's strange, but if i Run my WPF project directly, the Application.Current.Windows contains always the desired MainWindow.

Why the first run of WPF project breaks the Application.Current.Windows ?

Regards

Comment: Can you pass the user control a reference to the main window that it can store until it needs it later?  Typically this would be done in the constructor, but setting a property soon after construction is usually also acceptable.  Based on your code, it would look something like this: `navigateMain(new ucTableauBord(this));`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are trying to do here but if you want to get a reference to the parent window of a UserControl you could call the Window.GetWindow method once the UserControl has been loaded:

```
public partial class ucTableauBord : ucTemplate
{
    public ucTableauBord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += Load();
    }

    private void Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to retrieve the initialized instance of MainWindow in the userControl without passing it as a parameter.
Normally, the Application.Current.Windows function is recommended, but in my case it does not work at first launch if the project is started from Integration.ElementHost.
It does contain an element, but not of type MainWindow but of type "Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow" that I can cast.

Comment: Did you even try to use the Window.GetWindow method as I suggested?

Comment: This is the same thing, the GetWindow(this) method returns null at the first call, but not the following.

Comment: Even if you call it in the *Loaded event handler* of the UserControl?

Comment: Yes, until the main window is closed (so the project closed)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `MainForm` reference to the user control that it can save for later.  This is usually done in the constructor, but setting a property soon after it is created is often acceptable too.

On the main form:

```
navigateMain(new ucTableauBord(this));
```

On the user control:

```
public partial class ucTableauBord : ucTemplate {
    public ucTableauBord(MainForm mainForm) {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainForm = mainForm;
        Load();
    }

    private void Load() {
        ...
        //foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>()) { // Retourne 0 car il ne voit que ucTableauBord lors du premier appel
            WinMain = (MainWindow)window;
        //}
        //if (WinMain != null) SetMsgMain("OK Load.");
        _mainForm.DoSomething();
    }

    private MainForm _mainForm;
}
```

To keep the Visual Studio designer happy you may need to add a "default" paramterless constructor calling `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: yes, i have thinked this, but i have many users controls, and it's not optimized to make this everywhere.
morover, if i want using the user control in another context, i will meet the same problem.

Comment: And that's how "dependency injection" was born.